# CSS: Responsive parent div

Tags: css, responsive, div

estoy teniendo problemas con el div padre "box", lo que quiero es que el contenido de este div padre sea responsive, quiero que box tenga un margen a la derecha de 20px y que el contenido tenga un width de 100% y se adapte dependiendo del tamano del navegador, en mi codigo estoy haciendo el intento pero cuando el navegador es mas pequeño, este pasa del div sin respetar el margen que he dejado.

Gracias de antemano a toda la comunidad, entiendo que el problema podria ser el contenido que contiene div con position absolute, pero si cambio estos div, afectaria mi contenido, que es emular un input con div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.single-line {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#box {
   padding:20px;
   width:20%;
   float:left;
   background-color:whitesmoke;
}
#pslabl {
  position: absolute;
}
#ps {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 23px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
}
#ps:focus {
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1.6px blue;
}
#psinlabl {
  position: relative;
  cursor: text;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="ps.focus();ps.click()">
<div id="box">
<div id="pslabl" class="noselect">
    <span id="ps" onkeypress="if(window.event.keyCode==32){return false}else if(window.event.keyCode==13){alert('submit');return false}" contentEditable="true" class="single-line noselect" spellcheck="false"></span>
    <span id="psinlabl" class="noselect">Contrase&ntilde;a</span>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var wrapper = document.getElementById('pslabl');
var ps = document.getElementById('ps');
var psinlabl = document.getElementById('psinlabl');

function onValueChange() {
  psinlabl.style.display = ps.textContent.length > 0
    ? 'none'
    : 'inline-block';
}

function setpsFocus() {
  ps.focus();
}

psinlabl.onclick = setpsFocus;

wrapper.onkeyup = onValueChange;
wrapper.onkeydown = onValueChange;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ya que estas usando javascript y css podrias implementar break points y media queries, de ese modo cada break point tendra una media query definida, aqui hay un ejemplo simple que creo podrias adaptar a tu proyecto: [Ejemplo break points w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_mq_breakpoints)

Comment: Necesito que el cambio suceda en tiempo real, con media si modifico el tamaño del navegador de 1024 a 950, el input se saldra del margen de todas formas, a menos que modifique un tamaño especifico para cada tamaño con media, pero tiene que existir otra manera con div, no deberia agregar uno por uno.

Comment: Para que el cambio suceda en tiempo real puedes usar WINDOW, este link de ejemplo https://codepen.io/beljems/pen/NdyWdZ es eso lo que quieres lograr? l

Comment: Si, es exactamente eso, el problema es que los div de mi código están en position absolute y se continua saliendo el contenido de la caja principal "box", como podría adaptarlo al windows resize?